# excel VBA populate column based on other filtered column

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

I am trying to fill an empty sheet column based on a filtered column right next to it. This is how I capture the two columns to only include and perform on visible rows:

```
Set rng = Range("M2:M" & Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Set rng2 = Range("N2:N" & Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Let's assume I have a value in `rCell`. I want now to add `rCell` to all cell values in `rng` and put it into the same row of `rng2`

I tried to loop through each cell in `rng`, add `rCell` and put its value into the corresponding row of `rng2`

```
        i = 0
        For Each cl In rng
            rng2(i).Value = cl + rCell
            i = i + 1
        Next
```

`cl` manages to get the correct values of filtered cells of `rng` but it adds them to **unfiltered** column of `rng2`. Thus, indexing seems not to work!

Comment: Are `rng` and `rng2` set with same filter ? I'll explain by example, let's say `rng` is combined of cells `$M$2,$M$4:$M$5,$M$11:$M$13` does `rng2` consist of the same row number but column N, like `$N$2,$N$4:$N$5,$N$11:$N$13` ?

Comment: yes yes, rng defines the filters, rng2 are exactly the same rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like that :

```
For Each cl In Rng
    cl.Offset(0, 1).Value = cl + rCell
Next
```